# Как сделать проверку если курсор в таблице наведён на текст и при клике и выделении текста он должен быть курсор текст?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать проверку, если курсор в таблице наведён на текст и при клике и выделении текста он должен быть курсор текст? Стандартно он так и должен работать, но мне нужно сделать это, потому что я использую плагин, который сбросил это поведение.

Если курсор не наведён на текст и не выделяет текст, то при клике и перетягивании вправо или влево должен стать cursor grabbing?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обратится к элементу в котором лежит текст и через css задайте: cursor: auto !important;
Или же гляньте через консоль разработчика, есть ли какие то команды cursor на тексте или на родительских элементах где лежит текст.
Так же такая проблема может быть если присутствует стиль user-select: none;